# Independent and mutually exclusive

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Prove or disprove via proof that events $X$ and $Y$ can be independent and mutually exclusive if both of their probabilities are greater than $0$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Two events $X$ and $Y$ are *independent* if and only if $P(X \cap Y) = P(X)P(Y)$.
They are *mutually exclusive* if and only if $P(X \cap Y) = 0$.

In this case, $P(X) > 0$ and $P(Y) > 0$, which means that $P(X)P(Y) > 0$. If the events are independent, then $P(X)P(Y) = P(X \cap Y) > 0$, which would imply that they are not mutually exclusive!

In other words, the events cannot be both independent and mutually exclusive if both of their probabilities are greater than $0$.