# Independent and Mutually Exclusive Events

Tags: probability, independence

My textbook states that two events E and F are  independent if any one of the following conditions are met:
(i) P(E/F)= P(E)
(ii)P(F/E)=P(F)
(iii)P(E n F)=P(E).P(F)

Is it correct to then assume that if E and F are independent having met condition (i) or (ii), then E and F are also mutually exclusive?

Comment: No -- in fact, mutually exclusive is an incredibly strong form of DEPENDENCE: if one happens, then you know for a fact that the other didn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Independent and mutually exclusive](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/332378/independent-and-mutually-exclusive)

Answer (score 0):

No. Mutually exclusive or disjoint if they cannot both be true.

$P(E|F) = \frac{P(E \cap F)}{P(F)}$

As independent event $P(E \cap F) = P(E)\cdot P(F)$

$= \frac{P(E)\cdot P(F)}{P(F)}$

$= P(E)$